# CFLAGS is not taken into account, why?

Tags: binary, compilation

I'm compiling Apache 2.2.17 for my Mac OS X 10.5.8 Intel 64bit computer and I prefer the 64bit compilation so I give the necessary flags before the ./configure like so:

CFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

but the newly compiled binary just isn't 64bit:

file /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd
/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd: Mach-O executable i386

I'm confused.

I've tried variations such as:

CFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
CXXFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
LDFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

all with or without "export" or the "env" command at the start (e.g. export CFLAGS="-arch x86_64") and the result's unchanged.

What could be wrong?

Comment: You're asking a question about why your compiler does or doesn't do something.  Please edit your question to include what compiler you're using.

Comment: # which gcc-4.2 returns /usr/bin/gcc-4.2, so it should be gcc-4.2

Comment: As a confirmation of what I say, here is an excerpt from config.status (which is generated by ./configure command) from another Mac OS X 10.5.8 machine which is known to compile Apache with the correct C & CXX FLAGS: `code` config.status
configured by ./configure, generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64,
  with options \"'-enable-layout=DIYMacServer' '-enable-mods-shared=all' .'-enable-suexec' '-enable-so' 'CFLAGS=-arch x86_64' 'CPPFLAGS=-arch x86_64'\" `code`
Clearly, the C & CXX FLAGS are there. In the problematic OS X 10.5.8 machine, the same section of config.status contains no C or CXX flags

Comment: You don't need to screw with environment variables, you can pass everything to configure on the command line with `./configure CFLAGS="-foo -bar" CPPFLAGS=-foo -bar -baz"`.  Also setting CFLAGS (with environment variables or on command line) usually prevents any default CFLAGS being set, make sure this isn't your problem.  Finally, can a simple test be compiled 64-bit?  `int main(void) {return 0;}` then `gcc -arch x86_64 simple_test.c`.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. Well after several more trials, I have finally found out the reason. It's the ./configure just doesn't take any environment (or shell) variable into account unless they are entered in the same command line. I was entering the shell variables one command line before I entered the ./configure --[options] and so it was forgetting the shell variable (C & CXX FLAGS) All must be entered in one compact line, like the example you've given. Oh and that simple test must be absolutely compiled 64bit because gcc and flags variable are entered at the same line.